# How to combine (append) generic Lists in Java without using Javas Collection Framework?

Tags: java, list, generics

is there an efficient way to combine two generic doube linked lists without using the Collection Framework of Java? The lists are already sorted, so it is only necessary to append the second list to the first one. So far I tried this way, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach:

```
public void combineWith(List<T> anotherList) {
    DoubleLinkedList<T> list1 = new DoubleLinkedList<>();

    anotherList = new DoubleLinkedList<>();


    list1= this;


    if(this.next==null) {
        list1.next= (DoubleLinkedList<T>) anotherList;

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use `addAll` method to combine both list?

Comment: Why do you create a new list, put it in `list1`, and then promptly bin it?

Comment: and why reassigning the `anotherList` parameter with a new (empty) list instance?

Comment: what do you mean "without using Javas Collection Framework"? `List` is part of the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Intended is a merge of sorted lists. For walking with insert/remove, the `Iterator` or in this case `ListIterator` is useful. A double linked list could also move by pointers in the lists.

The basic algorithm is:

```
/**
 * Merge this list with another, both are sorted.
 * @param other unchanged list.
 */
public void mergeSorted(List<T> other) {
    Iterator<T> iter = iterator();
    Iterator<T> otherIter = other.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext() && otherIter.hasNext()) {
        T value = iter.next();
        T otherValue = otherIter.next();
        int cmp = value.compareTo(otherValue);
        if (cmp >= 0) {
            if (cmp > 0) {
               iter.insert(otherValue);
            }
            otherIter.next();
        }
        if (cmp <= 0) {
            iter.next();
        }
    }
    while (other.hasNext()) {
       iter.insert(other.next());
    }
}
```

Here I skip on equal elements.

My attempt at ascii art:

- Equal *(this, other)*

  ```
  :   :
  X = X
  |   |
  ```
- Less

  ```
  :   :
  X   :
  : \ :
  :   Y
  |   :
  ```
- Greater

  ```
  :   :
  :   X
  : / :
  Y   +
  :   |
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Method I posted below. Obviously this only works if it is placed within the class DoubleLinkedList, which I assume it is, since you set `list1 = this` which would only be possible if `this` already is a DoubleLinkedList.

`first` is the first element (or node) of the DoubleLinkedList and `last` is the last element (or node) of the DoubleLinkedList. If you don't have those saved as a global variable, I'd either do so or implement another method to find the first and last element.

```
public void combineWith(DoubleLinkedList<T> anotherList) {
        if(anotherList.isEmpty()) return;
        if(this.isEmpty()){
                this = anotherList;
                return;
        }
        this.last.next = anotherList.first;
        anotherList.first.previous = this.last;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some null handling for `anotherList.first` before assigning `anotherList.first.previous`, otherwise you would get NPE if `anotherList` is empty...

Comment: And I think you don't need to simply return if `this.isEmpty()`. You need to replace `this` with `anotherList` instead.